# asp.net ajax like reorder list

Tags: asp.net, ajax, reorderlist

I'm trying to create a draggable list to change the order some pictures are displayed in a product page. I wan't to be able to do this in the product edit page (same place where I add the pics and their description). So, when creating I have nothing inserted on the database and since the AJAX toolkit reorderlist only works with a datasource I was specifying the list as the source of the reorderlist and calling the databind method. In the item template of the reorder list I have a textbox to edit the pic description and a img that displays the photo. I can drag the items and the list gets reordered, however when I click save I can't get the updated text on the textbox and the order property on the picture doesn't get updated. I've tried manually getting the items in the reorderlist but they're always null even though the list shows 20 items the DataItem is empty. I've enabled viewstate and didn't help either.

Here's my code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ReorderList ID="rdlPhotos" runat="server" SortOrderField="PhotoOrder" AllowReorder="true" PostBackOnReorder="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                <%--<eva:PhotoView ID="iPV" runat="server" Photo='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />--%>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("http://eva-atelier.net/sparkle{0}", Eval("Path").ToString().Substring(1)) %>' Width="150" Height="150" />
                    <div class="formGrid">
                        <label class="formLabel">Title</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FileTitle") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <label class="formLabel">Description</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FileDescription") %>' />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remover" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ReorderTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlReorder" runat="server" />
            </ReorderTemplate>
            <DragHandleTemplate>
                <div style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:Red"></div>
            </DragHandleTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:ReorderList>
```

And below the C# code:

```
private void AddPhotosView()
        {
            if (_currentProduct.Photos != null && _currentProduct.Photos.Count > 0)
            {
                rdlPhotos.DataSource = _currentProduct.Photos;
                rdlPhotos.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

I'm new to Asp.net I come from a large WPF background, sorry if I'm making basic question :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For updating order of ReorderList items add your handler for it's `OnItemReorder` event. In this case your handler may looks like this:

```
protected void ReorderHandler(object sender, ReorderListItemReorderEventArgs  e)
{
    var movedPhoto = _currentProduct.Photos[e.OldIndex];
    _currentProduct.Photos.RemoveAt(e.OldIndex);
    _currentProduct.Photos.Insert(e.NewIndex, movedPhoto);
    _currentProduct.Photos.Save();
}
```

For updating `FileTitle` and `FileDescription` of single `Photo` it is easy to use `OnUpdateCommand` event of ReorderList and a button with attribute `CommandName="Update"` for each `Photo`.
And for updating all `Photos` at once just iterate through `rdlPhotos.Items` in next manner:

```
protected void SaveAllHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var riItem in rdlPhotos.Items)
    {
        var id = ((HiddenField)riItem.FindControl("itemID")).Value;
        var title = ((TextBox)riItem.FindControl("txtTitle")).Text;
        var description = ((TextBox)riItem.FindControl("txtDescription")).Text;

        UpdatePhoto(id, title, description);
    }
}
```

Remember that `rdlPhotos.Items` here are in initial order. And for identifying which `Photo` should be updated add hidden field with `Photo.ID`-value to `ReorderList`'s `ItemTemplate` like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="itemID" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```