# How can i implement Reordered list by binding data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

How can i implement Reordered list by binding data from **Database** without using datasource

While using database i am getting alert message

**"Reorder failed ,see details below .\r\n\r\nCan't Reorder datasource.it is not a datasource and does not implement Ilist"**

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this way,
```

1. Create a method to fill the dataset

   public DataSet FillDataSet_info(string _param1)
           {

   ```
           try
           {
               DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
               SqlParameter[] oParam = new SqlParameter[1];

               oParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@Column_Filed1", _param1;


               oDS = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(DataConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "proc_fill", oParam);
               return oDS;
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               ErrorMessage = e.Message;
               return null;
           }   
       }
   ```
2. Now use above to fill the ListView, GridView, DataList or Repeater

All you have to do is, create a method to bind the data in the GridView or other..

```
private void GridView_Bind()
        {
            DataSet oDs_GridView = new DataSet();
        string Param1 = "somevalue";
            oDs_GridView = oFCC.GetmRoleMaster_infoAll(Param1);
            if (oDs_GridView.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = oDs_GridView;
                GridView1.DataBind();



            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you,But my problem is not with binding data whenever i reorder the reorderlist it gives an alert as mentioned above

Comment: You need to add OnItemReorder in order to reorder the list. use this link to find the more details.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454972/asp-net-ajax-like-reorder-list